# In C# Lambda expression, how to determine a matched value?

Tags: c#, regex, lambda

In the following function (which works perfectly), I've been presented now with the challenge of having it not only return where matches were found, but what the match was... the code:

txtFilePattern is a pipe separated list of file extensions.
txtKeywords is a multiline textbox for keywords I'm looking for
txtPatterns is same as txtKeywords, but for regex patterns.

This is my own little experiment into C# Grep.

```
private List<Tuple<String, Int32, String>> ScanDocuments2()
    {
        Regex searchPattern = new Regex(@"$(?<=\.(" + txtFilePattern.Text + "))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string[] keywordtext = txtKeywords.Lines;
        List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
        List<Regex> patterns = new List<Regex>();
        for (int i = 0; i < keywordtext.Length; i++)
        {
            if (keywordtext[i].Length > 0)
            {
                keywords.Add(keywordtext[i]);
            }
        }
        string[] patterntext = txtPatterns.Lines;
        for (int j = 0; j < patterntext.Length; j++)
        {
            if (patterntext[j].Length > 0)
            {
                patterns.Add(new Regex(patterntext[j]));
            }
        }
        try
        {
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(txtSelectedDirectory.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => searchPattern.IsMatch(f));
            //fileCount = files.Count();
            var lines = files.Aggregate(
                   new List<Tuple<String, Int32, String>>(),
                   (accumulator, file) =>
                   {
                       fileCount++;
                       using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
                       {
                           var counter = 0;
                           String line;
                           while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                           {
                               if (keywords.Any(keyword => line.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower())) || patterns.Any(pattern => pattern.IsMatch(line)))
                               {
                                   //cleans up the file path for grid
                                   string tmpfile = file.Replace(txtSelectedDirectory.Text, "..");
                                   accumulator.Add(Tuple.Create(tmpfile, counter, line));
                               }
                               counter++;
                           }
                       }
                       return accumulator;
                   },
                   accumulator => accumulator
            );
            return lines;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
            throw UAEx;
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
            throw PathEx;
        }
    }
```

The question is - how can I determine pass which keyword or pattern matched to the Tuple I'm returning?

Comment: Don't do `throw PathEx;` Use `throw;` to rethrow an exception.

Comment: Technically speaking there's nothing wrong with what you're doing, but don't you think that's a bit too much code to stick into the `Aggregate` method? Have you considered refactoring that bit out into its own method?

Comment: I had thought about it - and perhaps even using a delegate at this point to get it so I could get this particular value - stream of consciousness coding at it's finest.

Comment: This method is very long. Consider refactoring it into smaller pieces.

Comment: I understand its length :) but I doubt that's whats stopping me from getting the value I need at this point out of the function. The rethrow catch was a good one.

Comment: And here I thought this question was about returning the matching regex. In reality it was, "How do I refactor this code." My mistake  : \

Comment: Actually, the second response was a good blend of everyone's comments. If not for your comment - I wouldn't already have this fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some refactored code. Kenneth had the right idea.

```
private IEnumerable<LineMatch> ScanDocuments2()
{
    string[] keywordtext = txtKeywords.Lines;
    string[] patterntext = txtPatterns.Lines;

    Regex searchPattern = GetSearchPattern();
    var keywords = GetKeywords(keywordtext).ToList();
    var patterns = GetPatterns(patterntext).ToList();

    try
    {
        var files = GetFiles(searchPattern);

        var lines = files.Aggregate(
               new List<LineMatch>(),
               (accumulator, file) =>
               {

                foreach(var item in EnumerateFile(file, keywords, patterns))
                {
                  accumulator.Add(item);
                }

                   return accumulator;
               },
               accumulator => accumulator
        );
        return lines;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
        throw;
    }
    catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
        throw;
    }
}

private LineMatch EnumerateFile(string file, IEnumerable<string> keywords, IEnumerable<Regex> patterns)
{
  var counter = 0;

  foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(file))
  {
    var matchingRegex = patterns.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMatch(line));
    var keyword = keywords.FirstOrDefault(k => line.ToLower().Contains(k.ToLower()));

    if(keyword == null && matchingRegex == null) continue;

    string tmpfile = file.Replace(txtSelectedDirectory.Text, "..");

    yield return new LineMatch
    {
        Counter = counter,
        File = tmpfile,
        Line = line,
        Pattern = matchingRegex == null ? null : matchingRegex.Pattern,
        Keyword = keyword
    };

    counter++;
  }
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(Regex searchPattern)
{
  return Directory.EnumerateFiles(txtSelectedDirectory.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => searchPattern.IsMatch(f));
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetKeywords(IEnumerable<string> keywordtext)
{
  foreach(var keyword in keywordtext)
  {
    if(keyword.Length <= 0) continue;

    yield return keyword;
  }
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetPatterns(IEnumerable<string> patterntext)
{
  foreach(var pattern in patterntext)
  {
    if(pattern.Length <= 0) continue;

    yield return new Regex(pattern);
  }
}

private Regex GetSearchPattern()
{
  return new Regex(string.Format(@"$(?<=\.({0}))",  txtFilePattern.Text), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}

public class LineMatch
{
  public int Counter { get; set; }
  public string File { get; set; }
  public string Line { get; set; }
  public string Pattern { get; set; }
  public string Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Marked as answer due to thoroughness and good refactoring. Doesn't compile as is - but did answer the question.

Comment: @kpcrash Yeah there's probably a few quirks since I wrote it in sublime text.

Answer (score 1):

How about you introduce a new variable to hold the matching pattern, and you use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Any`. Then, so long as the new variable is not `null` you have the pattern that matched, and you can return it within your Tuple.

e.g.

```
...
        new List<Tuple<String, Int32, String, Regex>>()
...
                       while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                       {
                           Regex matchingReg = patterns.FirstOrDefault(pattern => pattern.IsMatch(line));

                           if (keywords.Any(keyword => line.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower())) || matchingReg != null)
                           {
                               //cleans up the file path for grid
                               string tmpfile = file.Replace(txtSelectedDirectory.Text, "..");
                               accumulator.Add(Tuple.Create(tmpfile, counter, line, matchingReg));
                           }
                           counter++;
                       }
...
```